# Python rfind includes found character

Tags: python, string-parsing

Not sure it this may already have been answered somewhere, but I can not seem to come up with a way to search for the answer

Let's say I have string;

```
s=so/u/run
```

If I run the following

```
s1= s[rfind('/'):]
```

This returns the string `/run`, however I only want `run`.
How do I get only run?

Comment: `s[rfind('/')+1:]`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Looks like you probably want to use `os.path.basename(..)`

Comment: I'm using turicreate and when I've tried `os.path.basename` but when I used that I got type mismatch with the names later on so rfind may seem to be my only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rfind](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) method returns the index of the character found (or -1 if not found). You should be careful to handle the case where the character doesn't exist, unless you're 100% sure the string will always contain the character you're interested in.

Given that the index is what `rfind` returns, simply adjust the index you slice on by adding one:

```
s1 = s[s.rfind('/')+1:]
```

Here's an example of handling the case where the character you're searching for isn't found:

```
idx = s.rfind('/')
s1 = s[idx+1:] if idx != -1 else ""
```